# Can someone explain to me the intuition behind the discount factor for this simple payoff?

Tags: options, option-pricing, derivatives, pricing, discounting

Let's say you enter into a contract today in which in time t, you receive the difference between the underlying stock price and 100.   Denote the stock price as S.  Why is today's value of such a contract equal to:

> S - 100 * exp(-rt)

As opposed to:

> (S - 100) * exp(-rt)

I see the former in texts a lot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping it simple, your payoff at time t is:

$S_t-100$

The present value of the stock is $S_0$, it’s current price; and the present value of 100 is its discounted value as you correctly explained in your question.

Comment: Thanks! That's key that S in these is implied to be S0, which is already discounted.  This is super helpful!